Octomap - Save map using nav2_map_server
I am trying to save the projected map of octomap as yaml to use it in the navigation stack.
First I remapped /projected_map to /map in the launch file. I can see the map on rviz and here is the information about the /map topic:
>> ros2 topic info /map --verbose
Type: nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid

Publisher count: 0

Subscription count: 1

Node name: rviz
Node namespace: /
Topic type: nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.0f.76.64.35.5f.dd.f0.01.00.00.00.00.00.21.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Here the error I get:
 >> ros2 run nav2_map_server map_saver_cli -f my_map
[INFO] [1714251662.538637021] [map_saver]: 
        map_saver lifecycle node launched. 
        Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
        See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1714251662.538786381] [map_saver]: Creating
[INFO] [1714251662.538951516] [map_saver]: Configuring
[INFO] [1714251662.540357680] [map_saver]: Saving map from 'map' topic to 'my_map' file
[WARN] [1714251662.540394210] [map_saver]: Free threshold unspecified. Setting it to default value: 0.250000
[WARN] [1714251662.540419893] [map_saver]: Occupied threshold unspecified. Setting it to default value: 0.650000
[WARN] [1714251662.542250128] [map_saver]: New publisher discovered on topic '/map', offering incompatible QoS. No messages will be sent to it. Last incompatible policy: DURABILITY_QOS_POLICY
[ERROR] [1714251664.542321213] [map_saver]: Failed to spin map subscription
[INFO] [1714251664.544170667] [map_saver]: Destroying
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

Thanks for the help!

ros2 topic info /map_transient --verbose
Type: nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid

Publisher count: 1

Node name: map_bridge_node
Node namespace: /
Topic type: nav_msgs/msg/OccupancyGrid
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.76.64.d4.28.db.75.01.00.00.00.00.00.12.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): UNKNOWN
  Durability: TRANSIENT_LOCAL
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Subscription count: 0

I figured out a solution by making a new map called /map_transient which has Durability as TRANSIENT_LOCAL and used this topic for map_saver.
